# Orbeon 4.3 and localistion

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to create an additional language entry for orbeon 4.3pe following this guide:
http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/contributor-guide/localizing-orbeon-forms
I did this couple of times for older versions of Orbeon (4.2 and 4.0) and it always worked that way.

The moment I remove the app/fr/i18n directory the application starts to work again.

When I start the application I get this error:

```
Toggle org.orbeon.saxon.trans.XPathException
Exception Class org.orbeon.saxon.trans.XPathException
Message An empty sequence is not allowed as the first argument of xxf:format-message()
```

The error seems to come from oxf:/apps/fr/components/components.xsl

The additional information:

element → 
evaluating XPath expression
expression → xxf:format-message( $fr-resources/errors/form-title, ( xxf:instance('fr-error-summary-instance')/visible-counts/(if (count((@error, @warning, @info)[. gt 0]) gt 1) then 3 else if (@error gt 0) then 0 else if (@warning gt 0) then 1 else if (@info gt 0) then 2 else 4), xxf:instance('fr-error-summary-instance')/visible-counts/xs:integer(@alert), $title ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely scenario is that you are providing a `resources.xml` file which does not match the one that ships with that specific Orbeon Forms version. Try this:

- extract `resources.xml` from `orbeon-form-runner-jar`, or check [this version on github for 4.3](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/4.3-ce/src/resources/apps/fr/i18n/resources.xml)
- in that file, compare the English section with your language section, and see if resources entries are not matching

Comment: I started with a fresh copy and translated it. At the looks of it I made a typo which rendered the xml invalid (invalid comment with 2 <<).